# Transfering lot of images from device to windows

Tags: usb, file-transfer, windows, system-error

Hello Android Community.

I need to transfer something like 15.000 images from the internal memory of my Redmi Note 7 (Android 10) to my PC (Windows 10 46 bit).

I'm trying to transfer these using the (stock) USB cable, the problem is that it seems just impossible to complete the process as I 'm having (in order):

1. File not found error.
2. Path not avaiable errors.
3. Device not responding.
4. Explorer.exe freezes.
5. Other random errors.

My question is if there is another and less painful way to transfer these data (maybe using a linux virtual machine?).

I tried using  even google drive but it does not show my photos even if they are under backup with google photo (maybe i'll post a question about it).

Thank you.

Comment: Use adb. A much better solution is to create a full path list of all the images you want to copy in a file. Than setup a simple batch script to take each line from that file as file path of the image and adb pull it from the device using adb. If there comes an error, log the file path and the error in a separate file and continue. Even if the script cannot continue, you would know where the script stopped (at which file), which files have been successfully and exactly which of them are yet to be copied.

Comment: The benefit is that you are not sucking up resources with GUI so PC related errors and freezes should not occur. File not found or path not found errors shouldn't occur unless for some reason the media database of your device is corrupted or the device connection gets broken. That's what I think.

Comment: You can also do the reverse. Setup an SSH server on Windows (using Putty / Windows WSL). Setup Termux or Terminal Emulator on Android. Write a simple shell script that creates a list file, than copies each file to the SSH server hosted on Windows from Android. This way, you can avoid much of the freezes and possible file not found related errors that may be specific to using your PC

Comment: Done with ADB, thank you. (btw, i think that all of these issues are quite unacceptable in 2021).

Comment: @Raydar Totally agree file transfer problems belong in the past...